# Unable to cast Com object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type VsRunningDocumentTable4

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, visual-studio-2015

OS : Win 10 / 64bit
Visual Studio Version : 2015

When I check in TeamFoundation in VS2015, return error like below message.

> Unable to cast COM Object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type Unable to cast
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsRunningDocumentTable4'
>
> This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{86A4DA78-D580-4AE4-A1BE-F805BC663E04}'
>     failed due to the following error: No such interface supported 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

how can I check in TFS VS2015.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the VS2015?

Comment: yes... I already uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Does it work if you perform a check in action from tf command? Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I confirmed to success check in action from tf command. 
why doesn't it work in VS2015?
Additionally, so to speak, It works normally in Server PC. but it didn't work in User PC.

Comment: I had been installed visual studio 2008 first . and then I installed visual studio 2015.  did it make something warning or problem both visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem.... Try it  to  recover the Program Visual Studio 2015. ( NOT Uninstall and Reinstall Just recover) then, you can run it normally.

Comment: @Jaider, yes, I ran to this problem today and with Repair I solved the problem.